# How to programatically set theme to android dialog box?

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I am developing an application where in I have share and Rate options. When I click on these options I trigger an Intent which handles further proceedings. What I want is the dialog box these Intents open have some device default theme. So that different devices' dialog boxes will appear different. Also I have one dialog box for settings. How can I set the device default theme to this custom dialog that I have programatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Craete a theme in style.xml and then you can pass the theme to dialog's constructor as:

`Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.TransparentTheme);`

here **TransparentTheme** is the name of theme I've defined in style.xml

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply , but I do not want to define a theme anywhere, just use the device default theme.

Comment: It'll take device's default theme if you don't pass any theme for your custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Define this theme in style.xml and set it programmatically

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

        <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
 </style>
```

I hope this will help.Thanks!